# Incompatible types. Required: short, Found: int

Tags: java

I just can't understand the difference between this:

`short d = 0;
//some code
 node.accessible = d + 1;`

and this

`short d = 0
//same code here
node.accessible = d;
node.accessible += 1;`

the second thing is working, but the 1st one is't inteliji showes "incompatiable types" error.

p.s. node class:

```
public class Node {
int n;
short accessible;
Node(int n){
    this.n = n;
    this.accessible = -1;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to type `+=` instead of `=+`?

Comment: Why do you even use a `short` in the first place? In my long Java carrier I rarely found a scenario where using `short` instead of `int` or `boolean` would pay out in a full scale test. There are even cases where `short` is slower than `int` due to internal optimizations of `int`. Also, the potential of bugs due to unwanted overflows (without exception) is often too high compared to a possible micro-perfomance-improvement. Of course, it depends on your application, that's why I ask.

Comment: @Zabuza thanks, i'll note this, but now i am just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first version :

```
node.accessible = d + 1;
```

`d + 1` produces a `int`  as summing an `int` and a `short` produces an `int`.
The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) states indeed that (look at the last case, emphasis is mine) :

> **5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion**
>
> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of
>   operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a
>   numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing
>      conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted
>        to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted
>        to long.
>    - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int**.

But you cannot assign a `int` to the `accessible` field that is a `short` without explicit cast as `int` has a broader range than `short`.

---

While in the second version, a Compound Assignment Operators is used (`+=`):

```
node.accessible += 1;
```

As a consequence, in your case the result of the operation is converted to `short` : the type of the left-hand variable as the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) states :

> **15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators**
>
> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is Evaluations only once.

And more specifically in your case :

> Otherwise, the result of the binary operation is converted to the type
>   of the left-hand variable, subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13)
>   to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value
>   set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the variable.

Comment: The question is why `+=` does an automatic down-cast whereas `d + 1` does not. A JLS reference to this would be nice.

Comment: @Zabuza  finally I cannot delete it (accepted). I think that the question is not only the Compound assignment matter or the result type from `int`+`short` matter but both of them. So addressing both makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `1` in your `+ 1` expression is of type `int`. Adding `short` to `int` results in `int` which can't be assigned without a narrowing cast back to `node.accessible`.

Answer (score 2):

In the second sample,

```
node.accessible += 1;
```

is actually

`node.accessible = (short)(node.accessible + 1);`

so it works without problem. 
But in the first one 
`node.accessible = d + 1;` is actually `node.accessible = d + 1;` and it doesn't automatically cast as short and thus gives error as `(d + 1)` is of type `int`

Comment: The question has since been updated, but just fyi... the reason `=+ 1` would work is actually that it's `= +1` -- that is, you're assigning to an int literal of positive 1.  But since that literal is also a constant, and the compiler can confirm that it fits in a short, by JLS 5.2 the narrowing conversion (from int to short) succeeds.

Comment: I thought `=+ 1` is a typo which actually is `+= 1` and wrote my answer accordingly. But thanks for it ;)